# Decomposition of Homologry group as sum of homology group of path components

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to understand this proof here from Rotman's algebraic topology book.

[image]

I am specifically not understanding why the map is well defined. From what I understand, for the map $\theta_n:H_n(X) \to \sum H_n(X_\lambda)$ to be well defined, what I need is that the map $\bar \theta_n: Z_n(X) \to \sum H_n(X_\lambda)$ has a kernel that includes $B_n(X)$. However, it seems to me that he has only proved that $y \in Z_n(X) \iff y = \sum y_\lambda$, with each $y_\lambda \in Z_n(X_\lambda)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You agree he has shown $y \in Z_n(X)$ iff $y = \sum y_\lambda$, with $y_\lambda \in Z_n(X_\lambda)$.

He implicitly defines $\overline{\theta}_n$ by mapping $y$ to $\sum [y_\lambda]$, where by $[\alpha]$ I mean the homology class $\{\alpha + \partial \beta : \beta \in S_{n+1}\}$. Notice this is well-defined on cycles by the exercise 1.24.

It is simple to check that this $\overline{\theta}_n$ has $B_n(X)$ in its kernel using his parenthetical remark $\text{im}(\sigma)\subseteq X_\lambda$ implies $\text{im}(\sigma\varepsilon_i)\subseteq X_\lambda$.